# View not passing Id to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a Id of item from view so that I can delete it from db.
Here is my model

```
 public class ModuleVM
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    }
    public class IndexModule
    {
        public List<ModuleVM> Modules { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is method from controller that shows all the items from table

```
  public ActionResult ModuleList()
    {
        var modulesList = new IndexModule();

        var modules = (from module in _db.Modules
                       orderby module.DateEntered
                       select new ModuleVM
                       {
                           Id = module.Id,
                           ModuleId = module.ModuleId,
                           TypeName = module.ModuleType.TypeName,
                           DateEntered = module.DateEntered
                       });
        modulesList.Modules = modules.ToList();

        return View(modulesList);
    }
```

And now the view

```
        @using BootstrapSupport
@model AdminPortal.Areas.Hardware.Models.IndexModule
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateModule", null, new {@class = "btn"})
</p>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Module Id</th>
            <th>Module type</th>
            <th>Date Entered</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var entry in Model.Modules)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@entry.Id</td>
            <td>@entry.ModuleId</td>
            <td>@entry.TypeName</td>
            <td>@entry.DateEntered</td>

            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Action<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Create")</li>
                        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</li>

                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteModule","Module", new {Id = entry.Id})</li>//error probably here
                        }       

                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and now the delete method

```
public ActionResult DeleteModule(long Id)
        {
           // Mapper.CreateMap<Sorama.DataModel.SIS.ModuleStock.Module, ModuleVM>();

            var moduletypeId = Convert.ToInt64(_db.ModuleTypes.Find(moduleVM.TypeName));

            var module = new Sorama.DataModel.SIS.ModuleStock.Module
                {
                    Id = moduleVM.Id,
                    ModuleId = moduleVM.ModuleId,
                    ModuleTypeId = moduletypeId,
                    DateEntered = moduleVM.DateEntered
                };

            //_db.Modules.Remove(module);//also this shows error, don't know why
            Information("Your widget was deleted");
            return RedirectToAction("ModuleList", "Module", new { area = "Hardware" });

       }
```

**Edit: as per answer I tried to change my view**
On Pressing delete action I get this message in browser.

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteModule(Int64)' in 'AdminPortal.Areas.Hardware.Controllers.ModuleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

How can I pass the Id from my `foreach` statement from view to controller, when delete is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**entry.Id** should assign to **routesValues** instead of **htmlAttributes**

Here is the fix -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteModule", routeValues: new { Id = entry.Id })
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to do it doing this `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteModule", new {entry.Id })`

Comment: It is same; I just want to show you the parameter name. I'm glad that you figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Your not getting anything in there because your not passing anything to the controller. it is getting a default object.

There is no form on there to pass back data in a POST. Normally for a delete or edit on a grid you would add the ID of the record onto the route and use that to edit/delete your object.

So

```
public ActionResult DeleteModule(ModuleVM moduleVM)
```

becomes

```
public ActionResult DeleteModule(long Id)
```

and your action link becomes

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteModule","Module", new { Id = entry.Id })</li>
```

Then change your code to use the Id and delete the record.

Comment: may be it sounds stupid but in the action link `{Id = entity.Id}`, that doesn't work

Comment: Sorry its a typo - it should have been entry not entity. I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I made it entry, but probably you should have `new {Id = entry.Id}`? coz even with entry it doesn't work